# How to fake keyboard input with Python

Tags: python, macos, keyboard

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a Python script running in the background that can enter keyboard input into the app in the foreground. Maybe a python library that someone knows about. I'm wanting to fake my Mac's keyboard input in order to automate a very specific task.

Comment: Have you looked at using AppleScript to automate this task?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer to use Python as it's a language I already know. I just look into it more, and found no easy way to do it. Maybe you know a way of using AppleScript?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do it on OS X, but you might be able to simply redirect stdin it comes from a file. On other platform it's something like `script.py <input.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easiest (but non-portable - this would be mac only) to use [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/).  That is, of course, assuming that either the app you want to control supports applescript, or you have another tool which can type/click that can be controlled via applescript (ala [Quickeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/)).

Comment: QuickKeys look good but you have to pay for it. It looks as though there is no easy way to use Python, based on the lack of python related answers, so I will look much more heavily into AppleScript.

Comment: @Teak: You don't have to use QuicKeys, just something *like* QuicKeys that supports an applescript dictionary.  But that should be your fallback position - you should use appscript if the app you're trying to control supports applescript, as that would be the proper way to do this.  (Clicking coordinates on the screen is usually never the right thing to do unless you have no other options).

Comment: I am trying to control a program that has implemented its own GUI, so AppleScript will not do it on its own (as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @Teak: You could try to use something ala Eggplant, which is a headless VNC server that automates clicking by matching pixmaps on the screen with stored ones, that way your app isn't foiled by window positioning and the like.  I believe their server may actually be open source, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Use Appscript plus GUI scripting.  I have lots of Python scripts at my blog that demonstrate this.  Here's one:

http://www.libertypages.com/clarktech/?p=2413

GUI scripting allows you to script applications that don't fully support Applescript.  Here's a guide for the Applescript version of that.  Appscript basically lets you do what Applescript does only in native Python.

http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html